# Is there another way to form this CSV string?

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell 5.1.

I'm trying to form a CSV string where elements are surrounded by a single quote and delimited with a comma. Below is how I did it. Is there an even more concise way?

```
clear-host
$csv=""
$arr='TEST 1','TEST 2'
   
foreach($x in $arr){
    $csv+="'$x',"
}

$csv=$csv -replace ".{1}$"
$csv

# Desired result
# "'TEST 1','TEST 2'"
```

Comment: `"'{0}'" -f ($arr -join "','")` perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code by using the `-join` operator and enclosing the resulting string in single quotes.

```
$arr = 'TEST 1','TEST 2'
$csv = "'" + ($arr -join "','") + "'"
$csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the PS way:

```
$arr = 'TEST 1','TEST 2'
$arr | Export-Csv -Path .\TEMP_CSV.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
$csv = Get-Content -Path .\TEMP_CSV.Csv
```